# Making phone call in android

Tags: android

Can we make a phone call programmatically using android?
That is, can we do what microphone does exactly while making a call? (converting audio energy to electric  energy programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for this,

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 123456));
        startActivityForResult(callIntent, 1);
```

provide this permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

This will help you to make a call from your app.

Comment: Thanks dude. But I need the internal logic of how the microphone converts our voice signal to electric signal. And how it is get transmitted.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);                
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:01670100682"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```